# Testing diagonalizability of $T$ on $P_3(R)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem:

> Suppose $T$ is a linear operator on a vector space $P_3(R)$, test $T$ for diagonalizability and if $T$ is diagonalizable, find a basis $\beta$ for $P_3(R)$ such that $[T]_{\beta}$ is a diagonal matrix.

I tried to do the following:

Let $\beta$ be the standard basis for $P_3(R)$, such that $\beta=\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$.

Note that

$$T(1)=0$$

$$T(x)=1$$

$$T(x^2)=2x+2$$

$$T(x^3)=3x^2+6x$$

Then

$$[T]_{\beta}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&2&0\\0&0&2&6\\0&0&0&3\\0&0&0&0\\\end{pmatrix}$$

I checked the solution in the book. It said since $\dim (E_0)=1\not=4$, then $[T]_{\beta}$ is not diagonalizable. But I don't know why this works. Can anyone explain the reasoning behind it?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Relate your linear operator with its spectral decomposition -- furthermore, what's the relationship between said spectral decomposition and the space the operator acts upon?